# Atualizando campo datetime sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server

Preciso atualizar a data no campo date, do tipo datetime, em uma tabela, pegando a data do dia de hoje, por exemplo.
Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$dataHoje = new DateTime();

$sql = "UPDATE [RDO].[dbo].[ANALISE_CRITICA] SET
        TXTOBS='$objetoExtra',
        VLRECEITACONT='$receitaContrato',                                                             VLRECEITABRUTA='$receitaBrutaMarco',
        VLISSQN='$percentualIssqn',
        VLBASE='$baseCalculoIssqn',
        VLIMPOSTTOTAL='$valorTotalImpostos',
        VLCOMISSAO='$comissionamento',
        VLCUSTO='$custoDireto',
        VLADMLOCAL='$admLocal',
        VLRISCO='$risco',
        VLCUSTOFIN='$custoFinanceiro',
        VLADMCENTRAL='$admCentral',
        VLRESULTFIN='$resultadoFinanceiro',
        VLCORRETAGENS='$corretagem',
        dataAlteracao = $dataHoje 
      WHERE ID=$id";

$stmt = @sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
```

Porém, ao tentar atualizar o sistema me retorna o seguinte aviso: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string" Que problema é esse?

Comment: Tente passar a data formatada dessa forma:
`$dataHoje->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Em que parte? Logo depois do $dataHoje = new DateTime() ou direto no comando sql?

Comment: Você pode pegar a data hora do servidor ou precisa ser um input via aplicação? O SGBD tem funções que retornam a hora do servidor, getdate() ou sysdate() dependendo do tipo da coluna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@GustavoSevero, segue o exemplo do código, conforme [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18264290)

```
$dataHoje = new DateTime();
$dataHoje = $dataHoje ->format('d/m/Y'); 
echo $dataHoje ;
```

Comment: Retirei os +7 months, a data entrou no banco, porém com ano de 1905-06-12... Claro, mudei o format para ('Y-m-d'), tb

Comment: Colocando, EXATAMENTE como vc colocou aqui, a data entra 1900-01-01

Comment: Então, não sei cara, será que não é a data da sua maquina/servidor ? 

Testando [aqui](http://phptester.net/) está normal

Answer (score 1):

Peguei a data formatada como string usando método [format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) passando o formato desejado, lembre de colocar aspas no valor de uma data no update.

```
$dataHoje = new DateTime();
$dataFormatada = $dataHoje->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //formato: 2014-10-22 15:06:11

$sql = "UPDATE ....
          dataAlteracao = '$dataFormatada'
        WHERE ID = $id";
```

Caso a data venha de um input digitado pelo usuário no formato dd/mm/yyyy
use o método [createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) para criar uma data e depois chame `format()` para deixar a data no formato aceito pelo banco yyyy-mm-dd.

```
<?php
$input = '24/10/2014';

$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $input);
$dataFormatada = $data->format('Y-m-d');

echo $dataFormatada; //2014-10-24
```

Comment: Via aplicação aplicação mesmo.

Comment: @GustavoSevero, não entendi

Comment: Alguém havia me perguntado se eu estava tentando pegar a data do servidor ou a que o usuário entrar, via aplicação, então respondi que via aplicação, por um <input type="date"...